# Cannot import python package installed with apt-get

Tags: ubuntu, pip, apt-get

On ubuntu (specifically the python:3.7.3-stretch base dockerimage), I run:

```
$ pip install pandas
$ python -c 'import pandas'
$
```

And that works fine.
Then, I try to install the package [pygrib](https://github.com/jswhit/pygrib) (which isn't installable with pip), via apt-get, [python3-grib](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/python3-grib). I try:

```
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install python3-grib
$ python -c 'import pygrib'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygrib'
```

(Omitting the output of the installs for brevity).

Why can't I import pygrib? I am not inside a virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing *I* would try, would be to double check that the python you're calling is the same that you've installed `pygrib` into

- `$ which python`
- `$ python -c "help("modules")"`
- `$ python -c "help("modules pygrip")"`

(to inspect which python you're calling, and which packages are installed there).

If that's not working, then there's something off with the ubuntu package - so I'd then try installing from source instead;

From https://github.com/jswhit/pygrib

```
Clone the github repository, or download a source release from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygrib.

Copy setup.cfg.template to setup.cfg, open in text editor, follow instructions in comments for editing. If you are using the old grib_api library instead of the new eccodes library, be sure to uncomment the last line setup.cfg.

Run 'python setup.py build'

Run 'python setup.py install' (with sudo if necessary)

Run 'python test.py' to test your pygrib installation.
```

Comment: Thanks! I see that I'm calling the wrong python:
which python gives me '/usr/local/bin/python', and the pygrib stuff is installed in '/usr/lib/python3'.. How do I reconcile this?

Comment: You can call that python directly `$ /usr/lib/python3 yourscipt.py` or maybe just by calling `$ python3 yourscript.py`